# How to work with non-ascii characters in strings in C++?

Tags: c++, non-ascii-characters

When writing a program, I'm having issues working with a combination of special characters and regular ones. When I print either type to the console separately, they work fine, but when I print a special and normal character in the same line, it results in errored characters instead of the expected output.
My code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void initCharacterMap(){
    const string normal = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_[]{};':\",.<>/?";
    const string inverse = "∀Ↄ◖ƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WᴎOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ᴧMX⅄Zɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞʃɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz12Ɛᔭ59Ɫ860¡@#$%^⅋*)(-‾][}{؛,:„'˙></¿";

    cout << normal << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<normal.length();i++){
        cout << normal[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << inverse << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<inverse.length();i++){
        cout << inverse[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<inverse.length();i++){
        cout << normal[i] << inverse[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    initCharacterMap();
    return 0;
}
```

And the console output:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/H9bqh67WPZ/

When viewed in console, the \XX characters show up as unknown character symbol, and when I opened that log, I was warned that some characters couldn't be viewed and that editing could corrupt the file.

If anyone has any advice on how I can fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
After following the suggestion in Marek R's answer, the situation greatly improved, but this still isn't quite giving me the results I want.
New code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void initCharacterMap(){
    const wchar_t normal[] = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_[]{};':\",.<>/?";
    const wchar_t inverse[] = L"∀Ↄ◖ƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WᴎOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ᴧMX⅄Zɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞʃɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz12Ɛᔭ59Ɫ860¡@#$%^⅋*)(-‾][}{؛,:„'˙></¿";

    wcout << normal << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(normal)/sizeof(normal[0]);i++){
        wcout << normal[i];
    }
    wcout << endl;

    wcout << inverse << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(inverse)/sizeof(inverse[0]);i++){
        wcout << inverse[i];
    }
    wcout << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(inverse)/sizeof(inverse[0]);i++){
        wcout << normal[i] << inverse[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    initCharacterMap();
    return 0;
}
```

New console output:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hcM7JB99zj/

So, I'm no longer having issues with using output of contents of the strings together, but the issue with it now is that all non-ascii characters are being replaced with question marks in the output. Is there any way to make those characters output properly?

Comment: Take a look at `std::string` vs `std::wstring`. The later one is made especially to represent characters outside of ASCII range (`wchar_t` is larger than `char`)

Comment: First of all you will need to stop calling them "special characters" and find out what you are actually storing ;)

Comment: But *all* characters are special!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, guys. I've followed it and updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you code is using UTF-8 encoding. This means that single character can occupy from one to 4 bytes.
Note that that value of `inverse.size()` is bigger than you are expecting.

`std::string` doesn't know anything about encoding, so it treats each byte as a character. The output console is interpreting sequence of byres as done in respective encoding and shows proper characters.

When you print byte by byte each string separately it works since sequence is proper.
When you print one byte from one string and one byte from other things get messy.

The easiest way to fix it is use `std::wstring` `wchar_t` and `L"some literal"`. It should work in your case, but as point out in comets below on some platforms some characters may not fit into single wide character.
If you want to know more read about different character encoding.

The other way to solve your problem is to use a map which will transform sequence of bytes (string) to other sequence (string).
C++11:

```
auto dictionary = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> {
    { "A", "∀" },
    { "B", "" },
    { "C", "Ↄ" },
    { "D", "◖" },
    … … …
}
```

---

**Edit**
I've tested your new code and you should add code which configures locale for output stream.

On my mac (with polish locale), when building with clang, application ignores `inverted` values (`wcout` goes into invalid state), but when locale is set everything works like you are expecting.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

void initCharacterMap(){
    wcout.imbue(locale(""));

    const auto normal = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_[]{};':\",.<>/?"s;
    const auto inverse = L"∀Ↄ◖ƎℲ⅁HIſ⋊⅂WᴎOԀΌᴚS⊥∩ᴧMX⅄Zɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞʃɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz12Ɛᔭ59Ɫ860¡@#$%^⅋*)(-‾][}{؛,:„'˙></¿"s;

    wcout << normal << endl;

    for(auto ch : normal){
        wcout << ch;
    }
    wcout << endl;

    wcout << inverse << endl;

    for(auto ch : inverse){
        wcout << ch;
    }
    wcout << endl;

    for(size_t i=0; i < inverse.length(); ++i){
        wcout << normal[i] << inverse[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    initCharacterMap();
    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/nTYi5RbZgZXclE5r

I'm suspecting that standard library in your compiler also doesn't know how to perform conversion with default locale, so it prints question marks instead actual charters. So add this two lines (`include` and `imbue`) and it should work. If not then provide information about your platform and compiler.

Comment: The `std::wstring` suggestion will only work for some characters, depending on your compiler. For most windows compilers, `std::wstring` will be multibyte for emoji and some Chinese still.

Comment: This answer was great until the last line, which is wrong.

Comment: I'm actually flipping my downvote to an upvote because the bulk is right and useful. But _please_ fix that last line.

Comment: fixed and provided an alternative

Comment: This answer helped a ton with the issue, and now I've run into one more issue with the new code. In the output, all non-ascii characters are getting replaced with question marks. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah like I alluded to before, switching from encoding-unaware one-byte "characters" to encoding-unaware two-byte "characters" doesn't solve the problem. It simply changes the problem. Assuming UTF-8, what you actually need is a library that can actually recognise and deal with UTF-8. Fortunately, this is not hard to find. I don't remember exactly whether the featureset has what you need, but http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/ is really good for quick lightweight stuff. (Unfortunately half of SourceForge has been offline all bloody day -.-)

Comment: Actually I hadn't really thought about it very much, because it was only relatively recently that I integrated it into my project, but now that we're on the subject, I'm realising more and more that that _utfcpp_ project really is excellent.

Comment: Ah, that should fix things. I'll update the post if that ends up fixing it.
EDIT: Here's a [GitHub link to utfcpp](https://github.com/ledger/utfcpp).

Comment: yeah I should have posted an answer really but RSI over here meh plus bedtime